# SQL - Get previous amounts for each day

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a query that is sort of like a running total but not really. I want to get the previous weight (kg) and keep outputting that for each day until another weight (kg) is recorded then continue to output that until next weight recorded. Below is example of what I'm trying to accomplish (see KG column).

Current results:

```
ENCOUNTER_ID | KG   | DATE_RECORDED | CALENDAR_DT
-----------------------------------------------
100            10     2019-01-01      2019-01-01
NULL           NULL   NULL            2019-01-02
100            12     2019-01-03      2019-01-03
NULL           NULL   NULL            2019-01-04
NULL           NULL   NULL            2019-01-05
NULL           NULL   NULL            2019-01-06
100            13     2019-01-07      2019-01-07
NULL           NULL   NULL            2019-01-08
```

Desired Results:

```
ENCOUNTER_ID | KG   | DATE_RECORDED | CALENDAR_DT
-----------------------------------------------
100            10     2019-01-01      2019-01-01
NULL           10     NULL            2019-01-02
100            12     2019-01-03      2019-01-03
NULL           12     NULL            2019-01-04
NULL           12     NULL            2019-01-05
NULL           12     NULL            2019-01-06
100            13     2019-01-07      2019-01-07
NULL           13     NULL            2019-01-08
```

Comment: Tag the DBMS that you are using.

Comment: In other words, you want to fill the gaps caused by the lack of data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In standard SQL, you would use `lag()` with the `ignore nulls` option:

```
select t.*,
       lag(kg ignore nulls) over (order by calendar_dt)
from t;
```

Not all databases support `ignore nulls`.  But it is standard SQL and you haven't specified the database you are using.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Using Oracle PL/SQL. Thanks Gordon.

Answer (score 0):

A solution can be achieved by combining a `CASE` with a subquery that will fetch the first valid value ordered by data.

See the below example using T-SQL.

```
create table dbo.WeightLog
(
  ENCOUNTER_ID int null,
  KG int null,
  DATE_RECORDED date null,
  CALENDAR_DT date not null
)
GO

insert into dbo.WeightLog values
(100 ,           10,     '2019-01-01',    '2019-01-01'),
(NULL,           NULL,   NULL,            '2019-01-02'),
(100 ,           12,     '2019-01-03',    '2019-01-03'),
(NULL,           NULL,   NULL,            '2019-01-04'),
(NULL,           NULL,   NULL,            '2019-01-05'),
(NULL,           NULL,   NULL,            '2019-01-06'),
(100 ,           13,     '2019-01-07',    '2019-01-07'),
(NULL,           NULL,   NULL,            '2019-01-08')
GO

select
wl.ENCOUNTER_ID,
case when wl.KG is null
then (select top 1 x.KG from dbo.WeightLog x where x.CALENDAR_DT < wl.CALENDAR_DT
        and x.KG is not null order by x.CALENDAR_DT desc)
else wl.KG end as [Kg],
wl.DATE_RECORDED,
wl.CALENDAR_DT
from dbo.WeightLog wl
```

Results in:

> ```
> ENCOUNTER_ID Kg          DATE_RECORDED CALENDAR_DT
> ------------ ----------- ------------- -----------
> 100          10          2019-01-01    2019-01-01
> NULL         10          NULL          2019-01-02
> 100          12          2019-01-03    2019-01-03
> NULL         12          NULL          2019-01-04
> NULL         12          NULL          2019-01-05
> NULL         12          NULL          2019-01-06
> 100          13          2019-01-07    2019-01-07
> NULL         13          NULL          2019-01-08
> ```

Note: it doesn't explore the particular case where a first record is null.